# ¿Cómo no mostrar rangos de hora de una lista?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

Tengo un programa que me muestra una lista con el horario desde las 07:00 hasta las 23:50 y tambien tengo los rangos de turnos ocupados que son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestion es que cuando hago el filtro para que no me muestre los horarios ocupados, solo no me muestra del primer rango. Los demas rangos se siguen mostrando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta parte del codigo si me imprime:

```
echo '.....'.$horaIp.':'.$minutoIp.'....'. PHP_EOL;
```

pero no se porque sigue entrando al `else` si ya entró a la primera parte.

No se que es lo que falla.